# Crimping my own cat5e cables connection issues

Tags: networking, ethernet, cable, rj-45

I bought bulk cat5e cable so I can do a poe security system.

I bought a tester and it shows my cable is good.

The problem I am running into is that I am testing my cable speed on my ps5.

When I plug one end into the ps5 and the other into the modem i get around 560mbps

When I swap the cable and unplug the ps5 and plug that end into the modem and vice versa I get 97mbps. This is my second cable.

The first cable I made  would only work one way so I snipped the ends and retried  this time using pass through rj45.

I've followed the wiring diagram and checked the cable. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Please help

Comment: Get a small consumer cable tester that can test all 8 wires and connections. That should help you. I have one of these.

Comment: Also make sure your crimper is a high quality tool. These should be top notch to get a good crimp.

Comment: Often when signal issues occur on end-user crimped cables when the wiring is correct, it's due to poor crimp contact with the pins. It can be due to not crimping down hard enough, a wire that deviated just enough during production where the crimped pin looks like it's good, but it's only contacting the insulation, etc. To rule these out, use an ethernet signal tester or a meter testing continuity and resistance _(should be at or less than .03 Ohm's if relatively short - likely under 300' - but I'm unsure at what length resistance begins to increase in ethernet cables)_.

Comment: Can you update your question with a link to the exact cable product and connector products you were using? Also how long were the cables you were making, and exactly which diagram did you follow?

Comment: For a cable tester I have [this one](https://www.provantage.com/trend-networks-33-856~7IDLI00N.htm). I've had it for 12 years and it works great for testing cables I've made.

Comment: Are you using stranded or solid cable?  If you are using solid cable with regular RJ45 ends, that could be a cause.

Comment: Also, how did you wire up the cable - you need wire it using T568A or T568B - ie ensuring specific colors go to specific pins - to reduce cross-talk.

Comment: When I first started making up my own cables, I got about a 1 in 3 hit-rate. Nothing wrong with them visually but they didn't work. After a while it comes to you.

Comment: To my experience crimping an Ethernet cable properly is pretty difficult. Way easier is to connect a bulk Ethernet cable to a Ethernet wall socket. Therefore my suggestion would be to not crimp custom cables but instead get some Ethernet wall sockets and connect them. That way chance of getting a cable which is usable for high connection speed is much higher.

Comment: @Robert - good idea, so long as you get the right cable, solid not stranded **and** buy a decent punch-down tool that punches & cuts, not one of those silly, cheap plastic ones; otherwise it will be just as bad ;)